# Should I close database connection before a cloud function is executed completely?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using `knex.js` and `cloud function`.

Should I close the database connection before a `cloud function` is executed completely

code snippet like below:

```js
async function dailyReport(event, callback) {
  console.log('daily report');
  const results = await knex.raw(sql).get('rows');

  //Before executing `callback` function, close the connection to the database firstly.
  await knex.destroy();

  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your connection can be reused for a future invocation on that instance, then I'd keep it open, as an optimization.